# Subir archivos a carpetas creadas en tiempo de ejecución, en servidor ftp como FileZilla

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

Quiero saber si hay forma de subir un archivo a una carpeta recién creada, básicamente quiero que el archivo se suba en la carpeta que se creo con el siguiente código:

```
 //Creacion de carpeta
public void CreateDirectory()
    {
        string Path = txtNombre.Text;//Asigno Nombre a Carpeta
        string filename = Path;
        FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://servidor" + filename );
        ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

        FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();
    }
```

He intentado con un método para subir un archivo al servidor pero lo que pasa es que la carpeta y el archivo los ubica al mismo nivel del directorio ósea (la carpeta vacía y el archivo fuera, junto a la carpeta)

Comment: complicado que recibas respuesta sin saber con qué código intentas subir el archivo. Si le das la misma ruta, sin incluir el nuevo directorio, claro que va a quedar al mismo nivel

Comment: @Alfabravo tienes razón, en ese caso como establezco la nueva ruta. Este es mi código de la ruta: FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://servidor" + filename);

Comment: @Alfabravo ya me salió, le establecí la ruta en un Sting así:   ´string url;
            url = "ftp://servidor" + txtNombre.Text+"/";´  Pero no se que tan correcto sea